# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' get data

Tags: flutter, dart, unhandled-exception, formatexception

I want to take the product(entry) id in the database as the ['id'] of the object in the code, but I get this error
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vACL.png)
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TllQU.png)

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
    final url =
        Uri.parse('https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/products.json');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
          id: prodId,
          title: prodData['title'],
          description: prodData['description'],
          price: prodData['price'],
          isFavorite: prodData['isFavorite'],
          imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
        ));
      });
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Errorsuggest that, you are trying to access an element of a string with an index of non-integer value
Could you share the data received from the json file, and also printing **prodData** would be more help, as it suggest that **prodData** seems to be string rather than **Map** type you are expecting

Comment: -NSFAZyXWvwHxkz4y1lX
description
:
"fgb drtbt dthtf hrdth"
imageUrl
:
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Bob_McGrath.jpg/315px-Bob_McGrath.jpg"
isFavorite
:
false
price
:
1
title
:
"Edsc"

Comment: I try but ProdData is not printed

Comment: could u share whole of extractedData, so we could get more insight of data,

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```dart
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
...
    extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
      loadedProducts.add(Product(
        id: prodId,
        title: prodData['title'] ?? 'Untitled',
        description: prodData['description'] ?? '',
        price: (prodData['price'] ?? 0).toDouble(),
        isFavorite: prodData['isFavorite'] ?? false,
        imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'] ?? '',
      ));
    });
...
}
```